# How to show a post right after posting like SO with PHP?

Tags: php, post

Currently I'm doing this in two steps:

1.post it to ask.php

2.after inserting it into database,use `header("REFRESH: 0;URL=post.html")` to jump to the result page

But how to do it all in one step,say,like SO here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens using ajax, I'm guessing.

-User types post, hits submit.
-Post content is sent via ajax to the server where it tries to save it.
-If it is saved:
    The post is added to the page using javascript and some pretty animations and all the various listeners are added to the clickable elements.
-If not:
    Show some error.

I'm sure there's more to it than that, but that's probably the basic idea.

Answer (score 3):

SO does it using [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).  But for the easier win, why not just use `header('Location: http://example.com/post.html')` instead of a refresh?

Comment: Yeah, they're pretty different.  Redirecting the user using `Location` is loading up a new Web page, whereas using Ajax you'd be integrating the new display elements into the page they're currently on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a that refresh header, after processing the POST request, tell the client to view the result with a Location redirection header

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/post/$post_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

That kind of thing is done with Ajax. Using javascript to request small(er) amounts of data from the server, then updating the page, bypassing a full page request/refresh.

Here's a few libraries that may help get you started with Ajax and PHP:

[XAJAX](http://xajaxproject.org/)

[Zend_Json_Server (more complex)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.server.html)

[PHP Ajax Example at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp)